# Implementing Search query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, web

i am working on a blogging website and need help in implementing a search query using ruby on rails,i want to search for blogs(note:a search box with simple search would also suffice).My model contains blogs which are linked to users.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While we'd like to help you need to tell us more about your software, the 3rd-party tools you're using and your needs. Without that we have to make a lot of guesses. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to search as you type, I recommend exposing a search API endpoint in your Rails app, then making AJAX calls as the user types in their query. [Rails4-Autocomplete](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) documents this and has a demo implemented where you can draw inspiration from.

Comment: even a simple seach bar which dont search as i type would suffice,where can i get the resources to get started?

Comment: I would suggest cloning the demo in the link above and playing with it locally. The best way, at least for me, to get familiar with these concepts is by playing with them directly. Break it, change things, figure out why and where things fit so you can understand your problem holistically. If you're trying to learn how to do something like this for the first time, attempting to do the bare minimum to accomplish your mission objective might leave out knowledge that you may find useful to use as a base for your other learning endeavors.

Comment: I really wanna play with these things too and learn but the dilemma is my assignment deadline is closing in and got no time to play :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation/host a possible solution with plenty of documentation is [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) this gem searches your database and does not require a separate server/database to have efficient searching. The wiki and readme have great documentation to get started.

The downside of this implementation is that it may not be as fast as a dedicated solution like Sunspot or Sphinx and it will put a heavier load on the database. The positives are that it is cheaper if you are using a host like Heroku and uses the apps existing infrastructure (database), which may accelerate development efforts.

My experience dealing with the same problem you describe in your question lead me to [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search). I've recently implemented [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) and [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) (referenced in David S's answer) together to create an auto-complete search bar.